# adapted very slowly to any real evidence of feminine achievement

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'd appreciate some elaboration on the part in bold:

> Hutton had to modify some of these views when George Eliot appeared on the scene, and he might have modified
> them sooner if he had understood Jane Eyre, Villette, or Wuthering Heights. But literary stereotypes **adapted very
> slowly to any real evidence of feminine achievement**. If we break down the categories that are the staple of Victorian periodical reviewing, we find that women writers were acknowledged to possess sentiment, refinement, tact, observation, domestic expertise, high moral tone, and knowledge of female character; and thought to lack originality, intellectual training, abstract intelligence, humor, self-control, and knowledge of male character.

[source](https://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/womens-literature-19th-century-british-women-writers)

Answer (score 3):

The rest of the paragraph says that women writers were acknowledged to possess A, B and C and thought to lack X, Y and Z.

(Male) literary critics only slowly began to acknowledge the evidence that women writers *did* possess X, Y and Z.

Comment: Thank you. Quite clear.

Comment: It's scientifically proven that females normally lack Y but have twice as much X.